# Example of RailsCast dont work, Backbone on Rails,

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

i watch this video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1
I make togheter the video, when i come in part of router the index page like this:

```
class CozinhaSolteiros.Routers.Recipes extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '' : 'index'
    index: ->
      alert "This is home page"
```

this dont work, in my main backbone file exist this:

```
window.CozinhaSolteiros =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  initialize: ->
    new CozinhaSolteiros.Routers.Recipes()
    Backbone.history.start()

$(document).ready ->
  CozinhaSolteiros.initialize()
```

Im using Rails 4 and the gem backbone-on-rails like the video, the problem is  the alert doenst working and nothing appear on the console of browser, what is the error ? I restar server but nothing changes.

Comment: If you look at the source your page creates, is that JavaScript file loaded?

Comment: yes, appear this loaded in browser:`(function() {
  window.CozinhaSolteiros = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Routers: {},
    initialize: function() {
      new CozinhaSolteiros.Routers.Recipes();
      return Backbone.history.start();
    }
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    return CozinhaSolteiros.initialize();
  });

}).call(this);`

Comment: Ohhh, are some the indentation, the index: need back one space, kkk, thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Tabbing and spacing matter in coffeescript.  You have:

```
class CozinhaSolteiros.Routers.Recipes extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '' : 'index'
    index: ->
      alert "This is home page"
```

You need:

```
class CozinhaSolteiros.Routers.Recipes extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '' : 'index'
  index: ->
    alert "This is home page"
```